How can I automatically sign-in a user after they set their password in a Blazor interactive SSR page?
We have a Blazor (8) Interactive Server site. It is using cookies auth and was built using the standard blazor templates. I have an interactive Set Password page, which successfully creates the user (from a button click in a form); that user can then be used to log in from the static login page. We would like to be able to log the user in automatically as soon as the user is created, which is a problem in an interactive page because we don't have access to the HttpContext that the SignInManager uses, and the form doesn't POST in the usual way because it's using a SignalR connection to interactively create the user. How can I get around this? I can see the following options:

Make the Set Password page static (not a great option, as we will have to write a load of javascript to reproduce its existing functionality)
Add some javascript to the existing page in order to create the user and log them in via a REST API controller action method (again, not great because we need to bind that action to a DOM element that does not exist when the page loads - the docs advise against doing this)
Create a blazor WASM page for the Set Password page and log in via a REST API endpoint (quite a lot of work)
Somehow get the interactive page to automatically POST to a login url once the user is created (not sure this is possible)

Are there any better options? We somehow need to break out of the SignalR flow to perform an HTTP POST as soon as the interactive processing is complete.

The interactive mode usually uses a WebSocket connection. When using Cookie authentication to log in, the server reads and sets Cookies in the HTTP request, which is usually implemented through HttpContext. Only in SSR, the server generates HTML and sends it to the client. During this process, the server can access HttpContext to handle Cookie authentication.
I tried to test by accessing the api login method by sending post data after successful registration (user creation), but after successful login, the cookie could not be accessed in HttpContext.


When I configured the registration page as SSR to navigate to the login method, the custom cookie could be captured.

And in the relevant examples of identity,
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}

we can see that Identity components must be rendered on the server using static SSR because they set Identity cookies. By configuring any request to the components in the Account folder, the null rendering mode will be applied to force the use of static SSR, so it may be more convenient to use the "Set Password" page statically.
